# How to convert a word document into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, ms-word, etl

I have a word document that contains data dictionaries.

For example, a variable called FUEL is described as follows:

```
FUEL -- What type of fuel does it take?  
    1   Gas  
    2   Diesel  
    3   Hybrid  
    4   Flex fuel  
    7   OTHER, SPECIFY
```

I want to convert the document into a PostgreSQL table. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure. But what have you tried?

Comment: Sample content from the document? How are these "data dictionaries" structured in the document? *any* information to go on?

Comment: Thanks for updating with some info.

Comment: Flagged for reopen based on improved question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this sort of thing takes two stages: 1st, massage the data into a sane tabular format using text processing tools and scripting, or with something like Excel.

Once you have a tabular format, output the data as `CSV` (say, with Save As in Excel) and load it into PostgreSQL using the `COPY` command or psql's `\copy` after running appropriate `CREATE TABLE` commands to define a table structure that matches the structure of the CSV.

Edit: Given the updated post, I'd say you probably have to write a simple parser for this, unless the document contains internal structured markup. Save the document as plain text. Now write a script in a language like Perl or Python that looks for the heading that defines the variable, extracts the capitalied variable name and the description from that line, then reads numbered options until it runs out and is ready to read the next variable. If the document is uniformly structured this should only take a few lines of code with some basic regular expressions; you could probably even do it in `awk`. Have the script either write CSV ready for importing later, or use database interfaces like `DBD::Pg` (Perl) or `psycopg2` (Python) to store the data directly.

If you don't know any scripting tools, you'll either need to learn or get very good at copy and paste.

Comment: @user1663986 Reversed downvote to upvote; thankyou for actually responding and addressing the issues. Answer updated.

Comment: @user1663986 Come to think of it, there's a chance that ETL tools like Pentaho can cope with "data dictionary" style information. I guess it might be worth a look, though it's probably more complicated to work out if you can do it that way than it is just just write a simple script to do it. The format looks like it might be very easy to parse, too; look for lines with no leading whitespace as keys, then read following lines with a whitespace indent as values and split by tabs (?) to extract the ordinal.